# Pandas - How to write a better for/while loop using Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

i'm new to Pandas, currently i have a series like this one:

```
import pandas as pd  

index = [x for x in range(75860, 76510, 10)]
# number of occurrence
value = [1, 1, 4, 6, 7, 7, 7, 7, 8, 7, 7, 7, 8, 6, 6, 7, 15, 23, 26, 30, 31, 28, 22, 22, 21, 19, 14, 15, 15, 14, 12, 12, 13, 14, 14, 15, 15, 19, 19, 23, 25, 34, 38, 39, 40, 41, 35, 35, 30, 26, 23, 23, 29, 25, 25, 25, 23, 21, 19, 16, 14, 7, 6, 4, 1]

sample_ser = pd.Series(value, index=index)
```

This series represent measure and how many time they have been counted.

I'm trying to calculate custom parameters, but i'm using standard python for loops i want to know if there's a better way to accomplish that, here is one of the functions.

Thanks for help.

```
# return limits where 68% of total count took place
# starting from most_counted length we add the highest count closest to most_counted length
# if 2 count are equal we look for the next label, the one with highest count is choose

def active_area(sample_ser):

    # this is the label we have the most occurrence
    most_counted = 76310

    target = sample_ser.sum()*0.68

    total_count = 0

    high_label = most_counted + 10
    low_label = most_counted - 10

    while total_count < target:
        # index out of bound
        if low_label < sample_ser.index[0]:
            total_count += sample_ser[high_label]
            high_label += 10
            continue
        # index out of bound
        if high_label >= sample_ser.index[-1]:
            total_count += sample_ser[low_label]
            low_label -= 10
            continue

        h_len = sample_ser[high_label]
        l_len = sample_ser[low_label]

        if h_len > l_len:
            total_count += h_len
            high_label += 10
            continue

        if h_len < l_len:
            total_count += l_len
            low_label -= 10
            continue

         if h_len == l_len:
            counter = 10
            while True:

                temp_high = high_label+counter
                temp_low = low_label-counter

                if temp_low < sample_ser.index[0]:
                    total_count += h_len
                    high_label += 10
                    break

                if temp_high >= sample_ser.index[-1]:
                    total_count += l_len
                    low_label -= 10
                    break

                h_len_temp = sample_ser[temp_high]
                l_len_temp = sample_ser[temp_low]

                if h_len_temp > l_len_temp:
                    total_count += h_len
                    high_label += 10
                    break

                if h_len_temp < l_len_temp:
                    total_count += l_len
                    low_label -= 10
                    break

                if h_len_temp == l_len_temp:
                    counter += 10
                    continue

    if low_label < sample_ser.index[0]:
        low_label = sample_ser.index[0]
    if high_label >= sample_ser.index[-1]:
        high_label = sample_ser.index[-1]

    return high_label, low_label
```

---

edit: removed 3 of 4 for loop from the starting question, more easy for you to answer

Comment: First, index = [x for x in range(75860, 76510, 10)] -> index = list(range(75860, 76510, 10))

Comment: It would be better if you ask one question per question.  Right now I'm not going to even attempt to answer all of these, and answering just one is not good because (1) ultimately you're expected to "accept" one of the answers, so what if they're all independently useful, and (2) we can't know which of them is most important to you.  Perhaps as a start you'd consider editing your question to only contain one chunk of code you want help with, and you can use the help you receive to work on the other chunks yourself.

Comment: Hi John, thanks for suggestion, i'll leave just one for loop, then i will try to figure out he rest

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following (in my opinion more pythonic) script.

I added some test printouts. In the final version remove them
and convert the main processintg part into a function.

```
import pandas as pd

def nxt(ser, kk : int):
    """Get key / value from ser for key == kk. If the given key absent, return (-1, 0)"""
    if kk in ser.index:
        val = ser[kk]
        return (kk, val)
    else:
        return (-1, 0)

# Create test Series
index = range(75860, 76510, 10)
value = [1, 1, 4, 6, 7, 7, 7, 7, 8, 7,
     7,  7,  8,  6,  6,  7, 15, 23, 26, 30,
    31, 28, 22, 22, 21, 19, 14, 15, 15, 14,
    12, 12, 13, 14, 14, 15, 15, 19, 19, 23,
    25, 34, 38, 39, 40, 41, 35, 35, 30, 26,
    23, 23, 29, 25, 25, 25, 23, 21, 19, 16,
    14,  7,  6,  4,  1]
sample_ser = pd.Series(value, index=index)

# Processing
target = sample_ser.sum()*0.68  # Target limit
# Index of the max value. Low / high indices start also from here
idmax = low_ind = high_ind = sample_ser.idxmax()
trg = sample_ser[idmax]    # The max value
while 1:
    # Get index / value for elements before / after the current range
    l_ind, l_val = nxt(sample_ser, low_ind - 10)
    h_ind, h_val = nxt(sample_ser, high_ind + 10)
    # Diagnostic printout - part 1
    print(f'L: {l_ind:5} {l_val:2}   R: {h_ind:5} {h_val:2}', end='    ')
    if (l_ind >= 0) and (l_val > h_val) and (trg + l_val <= target):
        # Previous element found, previous value higher,
        # sum of values within the target limit
        trg += l_val      # Add the current (left) value
        low_ind = l_ind   # Set new lower index
        side = 'Left:'    # For diagnostic printout
    elif (h_ind >= 0) and (trg + h_val) <= target:
        # Next element found, sum of values within the target limit
        trg += h_val      # Add the current (right) value
        high_ind = h_ind  # Set new upper index
        side = 'Right:'   # For diagnostic printout
    else:
        print()           # Diagnostic printout - instead of part 2
        break
    # Diagnostic printout - part 2
    print(f'{side:<6} {low_ind:5} {high_ind:5} {trg:3}')
print(f'Result: {low_ind:5} {high_ind:5} {trg:3}')
```

Comment: Thanks for this solution, i will try to implement and report back.... So there's no more Panda-onic way to do this kind of things? We need to implement custom for/while loop?

Comment: Using Pandas methods (especially vectorized) is easy when the task
is based on sequential processing of rows in DataFrame or elements
in a Series. Here the thing is different: You have to start from
"maximal" element in the Series and extend the range either up or down, based on elements "enclosing" the current range. I'm afraid, there is no
other way but the custom loop, as I did. Or maybe someone else will propose other (more Pandasonic) solution?

Comment: Thank you very much, in the mean time i'm using your snippet and works as intended! From my little knowledge of Pandas i see no other way to implement something like this in pure Pandas like you said. Let's see if someone can help with this subject.